# nginx & docker - Forwarding port 80/443 to 3000

Tags: docker, nginx, portforwarding

I'm using docker-compose to config my app with a `meteor` app container and an `nginx` container, here's my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp.image.uri:latest
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    environment:
     - ROOT_URL=https://my.app.url
  nginx:
    image: nginx.image.uri:latest
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certs-data:/data/letsencrypt
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
```

I'm using `nginx` for handling HTTPS requests. **What I want to do** is to configure `nginx` so that, when user access `my.app.url` I can get the `meteor` app (port 3000) working on port `443`.
By the way, here's the `nginx` config that I'm using:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.app.url;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        root  /data/letsencrypt/;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443           ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443           ssl http2;
    server_name               my.app.url;

    ssl                       on;

    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout       10m;

    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers               "ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;";

    ssl_stapling              on;
    ssl_stapling_verify       on;
    resolver                  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/chain.pem;

    access_log                /dev/stdout;
    error_log                 /dev/stderr info;

    # other configs
}
```

Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: What you're looking for is configuring nginx  as a reverse proxy: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. This is how I modified my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp.image.uri:latest
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    environment:
     - ROOT_URL=https://my.app.url
  nginx:
    image: nginx.image.uri:latest
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certs-data:/data/letsencrypt
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
    links:  # new
     - webapp
    volumes_from:
     - webapp
```

And this is the `nginx` config file:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.app.url;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        root  /data/letsencrypt/;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443           ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443           ssl http2;
    server_name               my.app.url;

    ssl                       on;

    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout       10m;

    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers               "ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;";

    ssl_stapling              on;
    ssl_stapling_verify       on;
    resolver                  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.url/chain.pem;

    access_log                /dev/stdout;
    error_log                 /dev/stderr info;

    # other configs

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_pass         http://webapp:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `ports: 3000:3000`. The important there is the nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

**What I want to do is to configure nginx so that, when user access my.app.url I can get the meteor app working on port 443**

You can use the nginx_http_rewrite_module to redirect http to https permanently.
Change your first server block to this:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name my.app.url;
  return 301 https://my.app.url$request_uri;
}
```

more of nginx_http_rewrite_module you can refer this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return

About port forward, imagine your app server listen the port 3000, you can add an upstream block to the http block.

```
upstream app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000; #image the nginx is in same machine with your app server
}
```

AND add this line to your second server block :

```
proxy_pass https://app;
```

And now all connections from outside will be https and you app listened at port 3000 could also handle request from 443.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was when user access `my.app.url`, I can get the meteor app **(port 3000)** working on port 443